# Why would a PNG image be returning 404 from an Azure Web App when it works on localhost?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I'm attempting to load a PNG through a CSS `background-image` property:

```
 background-image: url("../../img/lp-background/lp-properties2.png");
```

This is what the browser shows me when I deploy the app to an app-service:

[image]

But the image loads perfectly on localhost.  The image is on my app server:

[image]

Why would this be happening?

I've tried:
 - Renaming the files
 - Moving the files
 - Deleting and re-adding the files between deployments
 - Redeploying to another pap service

Comment: The path in your browser capture is `<siteurl>/img/...` Maybe your relative url has too many `../` ? Isn't the root folder at `\site\wwwroot`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an absolute path in your code and see if that helps.

background-image: url("COMPLETE PATH HERE/img/lp-background/lp-properties2.png");

Answer (score 0):

As the Content folder is capitalised, if you are on Windows then this is case insensitive, but when you push out to Azure if it is a case-sensitive file system (e.g. Linux) then the capitalisation will matter.